# Is sending encrypted message and signed message a secure way of transmitting data?

Tags: encryption, signature

I know that the industrial standard is normally sending data in the following format:

```
Send Encr(msg, Sign(msg))
```

Is the following way a secure as well?

```
Send Enc(msg) and Sig(msg)
```

By secure, I mean no one will be able to read my message, and no one will be able to tamper my message.

Comment: @cygnusv, I've updated the question to remove the duplication

Comment: This [paper](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2001/21390309.pdf) could be relevant to you.

Comment: @cygnusv, thanks very much. The paper helped a lot.